# Connecting to a remote database from Azure Websites

Tags: mysql, sql-server, azure, visual-studio-lightswitch, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to 'collate' some data into one database. This requires me to connect to MySQL and MSSQL databases from my Azure Website (it's actually a lightswitch app using mysql connector.net).

Is this possible? I get the following error from MySql

```
Error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   at OpenCartData.GetProducts()
   at LightSwitchApplication.ApplicationDataService.UpdateLocalDBWithOpenCartProducts()
```

Which is normal for a firewall type block etc.

I can't find any documentation that states this is not possible, can you?

Comment: Just to be clear, the MySQL database is on a different hosting platform, NOT the azure one.

Comment: did you ever solve this? That's exactly what I have to do now.

Comment: Sorry, no I didn't get this sorted the way I expected. Azure was blocking these connections. This is from memory. In the end, I 'just' re-wrote the whole lightswitch app in php. Best thing I ever did (ok, maybe not 'ever'). Much faster and accessible from any browser.

Comment: This did get solved: It can't be done. I read somewhere in the documentation that the only outgoing ports an Azure web application is allowed is basically ports 80 and 443 to hit web services.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default MySQL Database from Web Sites? If so, could you be hitting an issue with the maximum concurrent connections? The default database allows up to 4 concurrent connections.

If you want to upgrade to a larger database you can do so from the provider [ClearDB](http://cleardb.com/store/azure)

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear, NO. Using a MySql database on a different hosting platform (opened up the firewall on that to everything just to test)

Comment: Maybe you could give some more information to help you diagnose the issue. Are you running MySQL on linux/windows? what are the steps you have taken to open the firewall. Is there a load balancer which many need configured to direct traffic to that machine?